# rdiff-backup command view backedup files

Tags: linux, backup, backup-restoration, incremental-backup, rdiff-backup

We are using rdiff-backup command to make incremental backups.My question is that how to view the files in a particular backup i.e, .gz file

Also how to recover all the files in a particular gz file

Comment: Your terminology is slightly confusing. It suggests that `rdiff-backup` is incrementally producing `.gz` files. Is this really what you mean, or do you have a `.gz` file spread across your backups?

Comment: rdiff-backup is incrementally producing .gz files so in these gz files i need to see the contents of it

Comment: These .gz files contains reverse diff, which are seldom particular useful by themselves. If you elaborate on what problem you are trying to solve, or the end goal is, perhaps I can give you a better answer?

Comment: @andol : So i have backup .gz files for 15 days.is there a way to view the files contained in .gz file

Comment: Sure, you can just run gunzip on those files, like on any other .gz files. But as I said, I am not sure if you will find the content very useful.

Comment: K.What is the command to restore all files in one .gz file using rdiff-backup command.Your comments have been very useful.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Check the [rdiff-backup examples page](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/examples.html#restore) - one of these should (hopefully) match your particular backup situation/scenario.